# How can I parse from an online xml currency feed to wp7 app

Tags: xml, parsing, windows-phone-7, converters, currency

So I know that the file is being read as I tested displaying the data in a textblock but can not seem to dissect the xml into parts that I want, ie, currency name and rate, and then add these to a list for selection and after perform currency calculations.

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace Mike_sMoney
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    //String curName;
    //double curRate;

    WebClient myClient;
    //public class Rate
    //{
    //    public String curName { get; set; }
    //    public double curRate { get; set; }
    //}

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myClient = new WebClient();
        myClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(myClient_DownloadStringCompleted);

        string urlRate = "http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        myClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(urlRate));

        //XDocument rateDoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(urlRate));

        //var rates = from rate in rateDoc.Descendants("Cube")
        //             select new Rate
        //             {
        //                 curName = rate.Attribute("currency").Value,
        //                 curRate = double.Parse(rate.Attribute("rate").Value)

        //             };

    }

    void myClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            //textBlock1.Text = e.Result;
            XElement currencyElements = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            var curList = from mRate in currencyElements.Descendants("Cube")
                          select new ClassRates
                          {
                              currency=mRate.Element("currency").Value,
                              rate=Convert.ToDouble(mRate.Element("rate").Value)
                          };
            fromListBox.ItemsSource = curList;
        }
        else
        {
            textBlock1.Text = e.Error.ToString();
        }


    }

    private void convertButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double x;
        //string urlRate = "http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml";
        //myClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(urlRate));
        //x = urlRate.getElementsByTagName("rate")[0];

    }

    private void amountTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        amountTextBox.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

}

```xml
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
  <gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
  <gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
  </gesmes:Sender>
  <Cube>
    <Cube time="2012-04-05">
      <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3068"/>
      <Cube currency="JPY" rate="107.06"/>
      <Cube currency="BGN" rate="1.9558"/>
      <Cube currency="CZK" rate="24.704"/>
      <Cube currency="DKK" rate="7.4397"/>
      <Cube currency="GBP" rate="0.82420"/>
      <Cube currency="HUF" rate="295.95"/>
      <Cube currency="LTL" rate="3.4528"/>
      <Cube currency="LVL" rate="0.6995"/>
      <Cube currency="PLN" rate="4.1707"/>
      <Cube currency="RON" rate="4.3728"/>
      <Cube currency="SEK" rate="8.8134"/>
      <Cube currency="CHF" rate="1.2025"/>
      <Cube currency="NOK" rate="7.5692"/>
      <Cube currency="HRK" rate="7.4820"/>
      <Cube currency="RUB" rate="38.6600"/>
      <Cube currency="TRY" rate="2.3468"/>
      <Cube currency="AUD" rate="1.2710"/>
      <Cube currency="BRL" rate="2.3942"/>
      <Cube currency="CAD" rate="1.3042"/>
      <Cube currency="CNY" rate="8.2398"/>
      <Cube currency="HKD" rate="10.1478"/>
      <Cube currency="IDR" rate="11945.92"/>
      <Cube currency="ILS" rate="4.8967"/>
      <Cube currency="INR" rate="66.8750"/>
      <Cube currency="KRW" rate="1479.25"/>
      <Cube currency="MXN" rate="16.8244"/>
      <Cube currency="MYR" rate="4.0106"/>
      <Cube currency="NZD" rate="1.6026"/>
      <Cube currency="PHP" rate="55.897"/>
      <Cube currency="SGD" rate="1.6476"/>
      <Cube currency="THB" rate="40.511"/>
      <Cube currency="ZAR" rate="10.2687"/>
    </Cube>
  </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Any ideas or help is much appreciated
mh

Comment: Hard to help without seeing the xml.  Also, are you having trouble parsing the XML, or doing the listbox?

Comment: xml is in following format `<Cube>
<Cube time="2012-04-05">
<Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3068"/>
<Cube currency="JPY" rate="107.06"/> ` and so on, I think its the parsing as once I parse into a variable I don't think there is an issue

Comment: [currency rate xml link](http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml)  xml link in full if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

**Edit;** I dunno if this is what you want. Create global variables under your `public partial class MainPage`

```
double usd,gbp, *etc*;
```

Then you can loop over the results in the var cubes with a for each loop, have a case for each currency and asign it to the global variable.  Sample below

```
void myClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.Error == null)
        {

            XElement currencyElements = XElement.Parse(e.Result);

            XNamespace ns = "http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref";


            var rates= currencyElements.Descendants(ns + "Cube")
               .Where(x => x.Attribute("currency") != null)
               .Select(x => new ClassRates
               {

                   curName = x.Attribute("currency").Value,
                   curRate = Convert.ToDouble(x.Attribute("rate").Value)

               });

            foreach (var result in rates)
            {

                switch (result.curName)
                {
                    case "USD":
                        usd = result.curRate;

                        break;

                    case "GBP":
                        gbp = result.curRate;
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }
                textBlock1.Text = usd.ToString();//displaying on screen
            }



        }
        else
        {
            textBlock1.Text = e.Error.ToString();
        }


public class ClassRates
{
    public String curName { get; set; }
    public Double curRate { get; set; }
}
```

xaml should be

```
 <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <TextBlock Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="344,6,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ClassRates}"  Foreground="Yellow"  Height="478" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,28,-13,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="431"  TabIndex="10">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbl1" Text="{Binding curName}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="70,0,0,0" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbl2" Text="{Binding curRate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />


                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: works perfectly thank you, to perform my calculations I need to store corresponding values in variables such as `double usd=1.324` etc. Have been trying something like `currencyElements.Descendants(ns + "Cube")
                    .Where(x=>x.Attribute("currency").Equals("USD"))
                {
                    usd=Convert.ToDouble(x.Attribute("rate").Value)
                };` or `if(x.Attribute("currency").Value=="usd")
                {
                      usd=x.Attribute("currency").Value;
                }`

Comment: You need to add an extra 'Where' after you check if it's null like 
`.Where(x => x.Attribute("currency") != null).Where(x => x.Attribute("currency").Value == "USD")
                   .Select(x => new ClassRates`

Comment: those variables only work within the `currencyElements.Descendants(ns + "Cube").Where(x => x.Attribute("currency") != null)
                    .Where(x => x.Attribute("currency").Value == "JPY").Select(x => new ClassRates
                    {
                        jpy = Convert.ToDouble(x.Attribute("rate").Value)
                    });` chunk, any idea how to make them usable outside?? will repost as new question

Comment: Do you want a separate global variable for each currency rate, instead of having them all displayed in a list?

Comment: yea if possible, unless I can take the value of a cetain rate out of the list for calculations but I couldn't get that working

Comment: I added code above that might help you but if you want a value from the list box do this `var selected = listBoxtrendResults.SelectedValue as ClassRate;
string selectedTextA = selected.curName  string selectedTextB = selected.curRate;//Convert this;`

Do this in a onTap event in the listbox

Comment: only reads in "USD" value for some reason, double checked for typo's but no sign of an issue

Comment: Your textblock is not the right size , put two textblocks in the xaml and print usd in one and gbp in another.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running into a combination of a namespace issue, and what I would consider a "horribly defined XML" issue.  The XML has three layers of nodes called "Cube", which makes it difficult to parse.

The code I give you below is not meant to be production code.  Instead, I present it to you so you can see the different elements that need to be parsed.

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\xmlfile1.xml");

XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
XNamespace masterNs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");

var envelope = doc.Element(ns.GetName("Envelope"));

var cubeHolder = envelope.Element(masterNs.GetName("Cube"));

var cubes = cubeHolder.Elements(masterNs.GetName("Cube"));


cubes.ToList().ForEach(cube=>
{

    var cubeCurrencies = cube.Descendants(masterNs.GetName("Cube"));


    cubeCurrencies.ToList().ForEach(currency =>
    {


        var country = currency.Attribute("currency").Value;
        var rate = currency.Attribute("rate").Value;

        System.Console.WriteLine("Country: {0}, rate: {1}", country, rate);
    });

});
```

By the way, one of the tools that I've found immeasurably helpful for working through these kinds of things is [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.com).  Being able to dump out various parts of the structure as you walk through them is incredibly helpful.

*---Edit: as requested, here's simplified code ---*

```cs
Dictionary<string, decimal> rates = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();

XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01");
XNamespace masterNs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref");
doc.Element(ns.GetName("Envelope"))
   .Element(masterNs.GetName("Cube"))
   .Elements(masterNs.GetName("Cube"))
   .ToList().ForEach(cube=>
    {

        var cubeCurrencies = cube.Descendants(masterNs.GetName("Cube"));

        cubeCurrencies.ToList().ForEach(currency =>
        {
            var country = currency.Attribute("currency").Value;
            var rate = currency.Attribute("rate").Value;

            rates.Add(country,decimal.Parse(rate));
        });

    });
```

Comment: For displaying rates, I am using the answer below but I would also like to store rates in variables for calculations. I have been messing around with your example but am unable to work it out, is there a simple way?? thanks mh

Comment: added an example of how to loop through the xml and save off the rates and currencies to a dictionary.

Comment: thanks but how can I create the `doc` as a file within my project??

Comment: I have `String xml = e.Result;
                XElement doc = XElement.Parse(xml);` but the whole block is targeted as having a nullreferenceexception, not sure where about though

Comment: You're parsing a document, so might as well do XDocument.Load();  If you take the first approach and run it through, you might get a clue as to what is coming back as null.  I still have the code snippet working, so if you're dealing with a different XML, it might be data related.  Again, if you have the ability to change how that XML is structured, I would do so, as the structure makes my teeth hurt.

Comment: I know, have no idea about xml as you can see, but its a 3rd party source for rates so cant change it, perhaps finding a better one.